# Unable to connect to Mysql Database using React Native

Tags: mysql, react-native, database-connection

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const dbConn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx',
  database: 'ucha_txxxxxx',
  user: 'ucha_axxxxxx',
  password: 'txxxxxxxxxxxx',
  port: 8090,
});

dbConn.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error in connection request", err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("Connection Successful-----------------------");
});

module.exports = dbConn;
```

This is my code for Database Connection. Initially I used phpMyAdmin localhost for testing my app, since I have to deploy my application, I have to change my database from localhost to a private server. I added the details of the private server and that is where I am facing the problems. I checked multiple times if I had entered the right details. I even tried using Pool but had the same issue. To check if my database connection has been established, I run

```
node index.js
```

in my terminal. It should display either of the two results written in dbConn.connect(), but I am getting neither. I even tried adding connection Timeout too but couldn't get any results. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

FYI- I am using Webserver [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5uyL.png)for hosting my database

Here is a screenshot of my code snippet.

I tried solutions from multiple websites and YouTube videos, even consulted my senior developer but couldn't get the expected result. I am hoping to get any kind of help from here.

Comment: MySQL normally runs on port 3306! Port 8090 looks like a port number you might use for Apache or the web server if you were changing the web server port

Comment: So MySQL is not running on 8090 as only one thing can be listening on a port. try changing that to 3306

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just tried it, showing an error as "Host '50.200.9.254' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server" 
I do not have any Host as 50.200.9.254

Comment: So at least you are not talking to mariaDB because that is a mariaaDB error message. So MySQL (mariaDB) is running on 3306 as suspected

Comment: You now have to setup that user account in mariaDB, so it is allowed to connect from a remote ip address.

Comment: That is probably the public IP address visible to the externally hosted database. Please note, you really should not try to connect directly to a remote mysql server over the Internet. Use VPN or SSH tunelling.

Comment: @Shadow as the ip address is `host: '192.168.201.142',` I dont think we are going outside a local network, or am I wrong

Comment: @RiggsFolly An IP address of '50.200.9.254' is unlikely to be a LAN address (even if it is, it is on a different subnet than the one starting with 192...). This is truly not the question that we should answer, this should be answered by those who run the project and are aware of the proper setup of their network and infrastructure!

Comment: I miss typed the Host as my local IP address, Sorry for the changes.

Comment: @Shadow agreed but thats not what was on the question originally

Answer (score 1):

Port 8090 is running a HTTPs Server on your IP, MySQL/MariaDB runs on Port 3306 (which is also open to anyone - more on that later)

The error you described shows that your user is not allowed with that specific IP (probably your IP address of your (home?-)router).

Usually you create user and permissions like this:

```
CREATE USER '<username>'@'<ip or host>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database>.<table> TO '<username>'@'<ip or host>';
```

If you want to access it from any host you can use `%` as < ip or host >

**WARNING**: You should never ever access MySQL over the internet (which looks to me like you do). Usually you don't even want to expose MariaDB to the internet ([`bind-address`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#bind_address) in MySQL/MariaDB configuration)

You also have many other ports open to anyone in the world - please check if all of them need to be exposed. Also you maybe want to mask the IP you used in your question.

If you are developing locally its probably best to install a MariaDB locally on your PC (e.g. via Docker) - if you have to use that specific server you should do it over some sort of Tunnel (VPN, SSH).